# How do I determine if a pixel is black or white in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I have this code in Python:

```
width = cv.GetSize(img_otsu)[0]
height = cv.GetSize(img_otsu)[1]
#print width,":",height
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if(img_otsu[y,x]==(255.0)):
            CountPixelW+=1
        if(img_otsu[y,x]==(0.0)):
            CountPixelB+=1
```

I want to convert this Python code to C++

This is what I have so far:

```
cv::threshold(img_gray,img_otsu,0.0,255.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY+cv::THRESH_OTSU);


for(int y =0;y<=img_otsu.size().height;y++)
    for(int x=0;x<=img_otsu.size().width;x++)
    {
        //Check Pixel 0 or 255 This is Problem
    }
```

How to I check if the pixel is black or white in C++?

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: in for loop I can't get value of Pixel 0 and 255

Comment: Oh,sorry My Topic Name is wrong

Comment: Reformatting the question to be more specific would be helpful.

Comment: In for loop of C++.I want to input condition

 if(img_otsu[y,x]==(255.0)):
            CountPixelW+=1
        if(img_otsu[y,x]==(0.0)):
            CountPixelB+=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `at()` function for `Mat` objects (see [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at)).

`img_otsu.at<uchar>(y,x)` will return the value of the element in the matrix at that position. Note that you may have to change `uchar` to whatever type of matrix `img_otsu` is (e.g., `float` or `double`). Once you get the value, simply compare it to 0 or 255.

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file d:\opencv2.4.2\opencv
\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537

Comment: @Orange does it also return that error if you use `float` or `double` instead of `uchar`?

Comment: @ Walfie I Try float and double.

Comment: @Orange Your `x` and `y` may be looping too far; try changing `<=` to `<` in your `for` loops.

Comment: @Walfile I try to change that.it same result.Can you example code for me?

Comment: @Orange Looks like the answer was accepted; what did you end up doing to solve the problem?

Comment: @Walfile Thank you very much.I can detect my problem.It wrong in datatype.